# How to build a modular app

Tags: android, software-design

I have an app that has about 10 different components (chat, feed, profile, settings, etc').

I need the ability to create multiple apps that each one of them will have a number of the components.

example:

- app1 - will have chat settings and profile.
- app2 - will have feed and settings.

How should i approach this?

I was thinking of building each component as a library and then for each app that i need to build a just connect the pieces like a puzzle.

Would this be the correct way? Or does anyone have any better suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develop an "SDK" project (like the Facebook SDK) which includes all the components (chat, feeds, profiles, users etc.) and you can use that "SDK" as a library in other projects. Use whichever components you want for that particular app.

This approach will make the "SDK" project maintainable and easily upgradable. When you are adding a new feature (say, albums) you can integrate it into the "SDK" project and use with the existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

An extensible, modular design of this sort is often quite useful for building larger scale software or software designed to handle a wide range of unanticipated future needs, especially if you're mixing in bottom-up approaches.

However, effective ways to approach this vary somewhat depending on the language and tools you are using.

An awkward part is how to make modules able to talk to each other when needed so that you can effectively piece them together like lego blocks. This will often become a practical need as the complexity of your software grows to a point where it will often cease to suffice to simply have modules completely decoupled from each other as stranded islands and only one "master" module to communicate with all of them. Often your needs will grow to require them to start talking to each other.

For example, if you are using a dynamic scripting language like Python, then it's easy for each module to publish its own public interface and you can start making modules talk to each other that way almost effortlessly.

If you are using a compiler and statically-typed language like C or C++, then this becomes a lot more awkward to make each module publish its own unique interface which is being directly imported and used by others. There you face the need to make headers accessible to all modules, worry about preserving ABI as you make changes, etc. A larger number of changes will break ABI and break other modules depending on a particular one's interface, so there we tend to design a bit differently.

In such cases, you almost always want a central software development kit containing all the abstract interfaces. Then your modules implement those interfaces and still communicate with each other, albeit indirectly (plugin A talks to SDK interface which is indirectly communicating with another plugin, B). The SDK establishes that central headquarters of communication, relaying messages from one module to another.